# How to store multiple data in drop down react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, dropdown

Hello guys i need help i want to store 3 data per dropdown option like for india label language and country code

```
<select
    className="select"
    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
    value={search_country}
    name="search_country"
    >
    <option>Select Location</option>
    <option value="in" >India</option>
    <option value="US" >UAE</option>
 </select>
```

I want to get data when user select **india i need country code, country name, country language**

Comment: Your problem statement is bit unclear, could you please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option data-value='{"code":"IN","label":"INDIA"}'>India</option>
    <option data-value='{"code":"US","label":"USA"}'>UAE</option>
</select>
```

Option can use data-* attributes which supports json automatically

Comment: But How to Fetch Data Like i want to add india code data